# compare package list between servers

Tags: server, dpkg, puppet

i know on desktop there's a graphical way to sync package list between pc.

on servers i've always been doing

```
dpkg --get-selection >pkg_list
scp pkg_list username@server:
dpkg --set-selction <pkg_list
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

unfortunately this looks deprecated: i'm not anymore able to do that. is there any other way? (and without involving external tools like ansible, salt, puppet  )

n.b. i don't want to sync configuration files or directory, just packages.

edit: added apt-get command to update/upgrade

Comment: What problem are you having with the above commands and what makes you think it is "depreciated"?

Comment: problem is that it is not working anymore: make an ubuntu fresh install from 14.04 and install a bunch of packages . make a new server and do that --get-selection and set-selection.  everything seems fine however apt-get upgrade won't work

Comment: What exact error do you get? Are both servers running 14.04?

Comment: i get no error: commands end fine but pkg list is not synchronized

Comment: Should that not be `sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade`